# How do I apply my function which returns a pandas dataframe, to a range of inputs so it returns individual dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, stock, alpha-vantage

I am using the alpha_vantage API in python which returns a Pandas dataframe table.

I have written a function, below, which takes a stock name, resets the index of the dataframe and renames it. How do I apply this function to a few inputs so it brings back individual dataframes for them? At the moment, I have to do this manually and run the function individually for each input.

Would it work if I create a pandas series with the list of stocks, and apply the function to the series?

```
def get_stock(ticker):
    stock, meta_data = ts.get_daily_adjusted(symbol=ticker, outputsize='compact')
    ticker = pd.DataFrame(stock)
    ticker = ticker.reset_index()
    return ticker
```

To make this dataframe available outside of the function, I was running it as below:

```
example = get_stock('XX')
```

`example` is therefore the returned dataframe variable.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the globals variable to create different variables:

```
def get_stock(ticker):
    ...

for symbol in [list_of_symbols]:
    globals()[symbol + '_df'] = get_stock(symbol)
```

Of course you could use any other name for the dataframes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am not sure how to implement this - could you break down what is happening in the for loop?

Comment: In the list_of_symbols you have to put the names (strings) of the stock dataframes you want to get (such as the 'XX' in you example). In the for loop you are creating a dataframe variable named after the stock name plus the extension '_df', if you use ['XX'] as the [list_of_symbols] this would create a varibale called XX_df.

Comment: Now that I have these individual dataframes, it is possible to apply one function to them all? For example, I would like to append a specific value from each one to a list:


`closing = []
def closing_price(ticker):
    close = ticker['4. close'].iloc[0]
    closing.append(close)`

Comment: In this case I would recommend not to create variables for every individual dataframe but create a list / dictionary instead in which you put all the different dataframes. Then you can either use a function like 'map' to apply a function to all elements or just use a for loop to loop over all the elements.